# flutter_inappwebview isn't working on ios

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, webview

I am using the flutter_inappwebview movie to show my own web page in the application. It previously worked smoothly on both Android and iOS devices. But webview no longer works on my iOS device. Nothing appears on the screen. It still works fine on my Android device. My codes are as follows:

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';
import 'package:i_have_ideaa/main.dart';

class WebViewer extends StatefulWidget {
final String code;
const WebViewer({Key? key, required this.code}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<WebViewer> createState() => _WebViewerState();
}

class _WebViewerState extends State<WebViewer> {
 String paths = 'google.com';
 late PullToRefreshController pullToRefreshController;
 InAppWebViewGroupOptions options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
  crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
    useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
  ),
  android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
    useHybridComposition: true,
  ),
  ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
    allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
  ));
 InAppWebViewController? _webViewController;
 double progress = 0;

 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();
 print(widget.code);

 pullToRefreshController = PullToRefreshController(
  options: PullToRefreshOptions(
    color: Colors.blue,
  ),
  onRefresh: () async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      _webViewController?.reload();
    } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
      _webViewController?.loadUrl(
          urlRequest:
          URLRequest(url: await _webViewController?.getUrl()));
    }
  },
);
 }

 @override
 void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
 }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
 return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(size.height * 
 0.035),),
     ),
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Text(
      'Bir Fikrim Var',
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: size.height * 0.03,
        fontStyle: FontStyle.italic,
      ),
    ),
    backgroundColor: customColor,
   ),
    body: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        child: InAppWebView(
          initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse(paths)),
          pullToRefreshController: pullToRefreshController,
          onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
            _webViewController = controller;
          },
          initialOptions: options,
          androidOnPermissionRequest:
              (controller, origin, resources) async {
            return PermissionRequestResponse(
                resources: resources,
                action: PermissionRequestResponseAction.GRANT);
          },
          onProgressChanged: (controller, progress) {
            if (progress == 100) {
              pullToRefreshController.endRefreshing();
            }
            setState(() {
              this.progress = progress / 100;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
      progress < 1.0
          ? LinearProgressIndicator(value: progress)
          : Container(),
    ],
  ),
);
  } 
 }
```

If you deem necessary, I can also share my info.plist and podfile codes. I researched what the problem was but I couldn't figure it out. Thanks already for your help.

Comment: I have same problem, you found a solution?